# How to explore different parameter values in Python to maximise a value returned by a function

Tags: optimization, parameters

If I have a function that returns a float representing e.g. profit generated from trading a stock (though I have come across such a problem with various tasks), and the profit varies according to various parameters passed to the function, is there a Python library that can be used to efficiently explore the parameter space?

I could carry out a naive approach where I try every single parameter value, but that could take a very long time depending on the number of parameters and range of values.

I have heard of MCMC and the idea of going through a number of steps to explore parameters, where extreme values might be attempted, and it is possible to reverse back to values that work better, but I have no idea if it applies here as MCMC appears to concern probabilities (and Bayesian statistics) - I am looking for something fairly simple if it exists.

I am imagining something like below, where the parameters have a range of possible values, and there is a function that tries parameter values in a way that is more efficient than just trying every single combination. Is this possible using a reasonably simple Python library?

```
# define a range of possible values for parameters
a = [2.0,2.1,2.2,2.3,2.4]
b = [1.2,1.3,2.4]
c = [float(x) for x in range(1,1000)]
d = [112.0,113.0,114.0]
e = [3.0,3.1]
f = [9.0,10.0,11.0,12.0]
g = [float(x) for x in range(5,36)]


def profit(a,b,c,d,e,f,g):
    # carry out calculations using parameters
    return profit

n_steps = 1000

def optimize(n_steps,a,b,c,d,e,f,g):
    for x in range(0,n_steps):
        # try profit() using different values within the range of each parameter a-g in attempt to find those that produce largest profit
        # i.e. for each step in n_step call profit() with one float value for each of a-g
    return a,b,c,d,e,f,g # return set of parameters producing largest profit within n_steps
```